# Conventions to indicate deprecated command line options

Tags: command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

What conventions exist to notify users that a given command line option is deprecated, and may be removed in future versions? In particular, what conventions do popular software packages use?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I think, is to make an update where if you try to use that command line option, it will work, but there will be a message saying it will be terminated soon. Wait some time, then update again with that option gone. That way frequent users of that option will have a head's up, and they would be well prepared for the change.